# An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1e) in Coldfusion XML output

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am attempting to output a query to a simple XML document. I have used this same code multiple times for other queries and it worked fine. It seems there is a bad character in the description field somewhere and XMLformat() is not filtering it out. I have tried numerous REReplace() filters to no avail. Also tried Ben Nadel's technique found here. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1155-Cleaning-High-Ascii-Values-For-Web-Safeness-In-ColdFusion.htm and everything has resulted in the same error. I did dump the output and search for bad characters and I found nothing. This simple thing has turned into quite the mystery. I am using the code below.

```
<cfquery name="list" datasource="theDatasource">
SELECT ItemID, ItemCode, BrandName, description
FROM theTable
</cfquery>

<cfxml variable="outputXML">
<itemsBrand>
    <cfoutput query="list">
    <itemBrand>
        <ItemID>#XmlFormat(ItemID)#</ItemID>
        <ItemCode>#XmlFormat(ItemCode)#</ItemCode>
        <BrandName>#XmlFormat(BrandName)#</BrandName>
        <description>#XmlFormat(description)#</description>
    </itemBrand>
    </cfoutput>
</itemsBrand>
</cfxml>

<cffile action="write" file="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())#itemBrand.xml" output="#toString(outputXML)#"/>
```

Is resulting in the error "An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1e) was found in the element content of the document." Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It seems a bit odd it's barfing on a `0x1E`, which is just a greater-than symbol.</strike> (edit: no it ain't; not sure why I came to that conclusion. AC).

It might be an idea to swap out the `<cfxml>` for `<cfsavecontent>` temporarily so you can build the string, then parse it to find out what's not right about it. That should give you more clue how to sort it out. But `xmlFormat()` is supposed to deal with wayward angle-brackets.

One other thing: if all you're doing with this XML is to then serialise it and write it to file, you don't actually need to use `<cfxml>` anyhow. Just continue to use `<cfsavecontent>` anyhow. If you want a string: just make a string.

Comment: I ended up dumping the content as Adam recommended and ran it through and XML validator. The problem was being caused by the Unicode: 0x1e character that was hidden. I had to turn on view hidden characters in my text editor delete the problematic character then copy and paste all the code to a new file. Thanks for the help Adam.

Comment: NP [etc... so my response is long enough to post]

Comment: As far as I can tell 0x1e is not a greater than symbol but an unprintable control character?

Comment: Correct. Not sure why I decided it was a >. Will updated.